# ASP.Net button IsPostBack

Tags: asp.net, button, ispostback

There is a button on the page which captures the user's selections and
calls another page.

For some reason is it raising the **!IsPostBack**
module on the page load event on the page with the button.

This doesn't make sense to me
since this is definite a PostBack event when the user clicks the
button.

I have provided the code on my button below.  Thanks for your
help!

```
<asp:Button ID="selectedList" runat="server" Text="Search" 
     CausesValidation="false" PostBackUrl="~/Listing.aspx"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PostBackURL makes it so that the landing page (~/Listing.aspx) will always detect a !PostBack, even if you are in Listing.aspx itself.

It's equivalent to creating a button with "Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)" hooked into it's click event.

Answer (score 1):

This is the life cycle and slight of hand that makes it work.

read this post: http://forums.asp.net/p/1517228/3642463.aspx

Comment: FYI I have read this book completly and this is my favourite Book.
 
There is nothing here that says, Server.Transfer starts the Page Life Cycle.
 
I think you confused by the term Cross Post Back, which is only used in PostBackURL case (not server.transfer)

Comment: I'm not sure how that relats to my question.  Is this the correct link?  ~susan~

Answer (score 1):

It is a postback it is not a actual postback that is happening to your Listing.aspx but simply a redirect. If you want something to happen during the postback you can write a event handler for the button and then redirect to the Listing.aspx inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If the page the button is, is listing.aspx, then you will get a postback, otherwise check the source that is generated for the button. is it having __dopostback ??

Comment: The button is on my master page and redirects to listting.aspx.

Comment: Yeah.. Here is the problem. Since this button is on master page, it loaded again when page is redirected. This is basic .net concept